# Display JSON File content using PHP

Tags: php, json

How can i display (echo) the JSON File content, like here, NOT DECODED?
http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/index.php

Thank You!

Comment: A JSON file is just a text file.  If you want to display it, then just read in the file and print it out.

Comment: Thank You!
Write this as an answer and i will accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your on php 4.5 or above you can use the JSON_PRETTY_PRINT.

```
$json_string = json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```